# How to handle webview error and clear the warning?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, error-handling

I'm using a webview that loads a login page and I'm trying to handle the error when there is no internet connection. 'onError' prop works as expected. However I still see the yellow warning in my simulator. Any ideas how to disable it through the code? (NOT by hiding it through the simulator setting)

```
<WebView
   source={{ uri: myURL }}
   onError={() => this.setState({ error: true })}
   onLoadStart={this._lookForCookies}
   onMessage={this._onReceiveCookies} />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is only appearing because you're running a debuggable build, and defining a value for the `onError` prop doesn't prevent the warning from firing.

If it's really bothering you, use `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Encountered an error loading page'])`.

PS: check out `NetInfo` for a way to proactively determine if the user doesn't have network; it will give you more accurate details of their state.